# Position of container change in localization. Any Suggestion

Tags: css, html

I want to add a fixed feedback button in right sidebar of browser. Its appear fine in default view, but when i move for localization for another language some how it change its right position. I want to keep it on same location.

Note: I have to use fixed postion and transform properties for some reasons. Any other idea welcome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Feedback</title>
        <style>
.feedback { position: fixed; right: -32px; top: 100px; border: solid 1px #a2a6ff; padding: 5px 10px; transform: rotate(270deg); font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 18px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; background: #e1e8ff;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="feedback">Feedback</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question isn't too clear. Your code example looks fine and doesn't consider localization. Show us the bit of code that goes wrong please :)

Comment: @RickvanLieshout Please try to to change Feedback text to any long text , ie:  <div class="feedback">FeedbackForAnotherLanguage</div> will show you the position changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser renders your element before the transform is applied to it. This results in the element being positioned as if it were not rotated, but the rotation is still applied to it. You can fix this by changing the transform-origin, which determins the point the element is rotated around of. I provided a code snippet with the solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Feedback</title>
<style>
.feedback { border: solid 1px #a2a6ff; padding: 5px 10px; transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: right bottom; font-size: 16px; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 18px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; background: #e1e8ff;}
</style>
</head>

<body style="height: 400px;">
<div style="position:fixed; right:0; top: 0px;">
<div class="feedback">F</div>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed; right:0; top: 50px;">
<div class="feedback">Feedback</div>
</div>
<div style="position:fixed; right:0; top: 150px;">
<div class="feedback">Long Feedback very long like super long</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks  @Maharkus :)